# How To Format A Number to Precision in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

What is the most direct, & efficient way to do this in Elixir?

```
Starting number: 123.101

Ending number: 123.101000 # Adding 3 digits to the precision of a float.

Starting number: 123

Ending number: 123.000 # Adding 3 digits to the precision of an integer.

Starting number: 123.101

Ending number: 123.1 # removing precision

Starting number: 123.000

Ending number: 123 # removing precision
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just want to supply a alternative to Dogbert's excellent answer.

It is also possible to use :erlang.float_to_binary/2

ex.

```
iex(5)> :erlang.float_to_binary(123.101, [decimals: 6])
"123.101000"

iex(6)> :erlang.float_to_binary(123.0, [decimals: 3])
"123.000"

iex(7)> :erlang.float_to_binary(123.101, [decimals: 1])
"123.1"

iex(8)> :erlang.float_to_binary(123.000, [decimals: 0])
"123"
```

Comment: This is way better than my answer! I checked `Float.to_string` but it didn't have any options and I forgot to check the `float_to_*` functions in Erlang.

Comment: @Serafeim Are you sure? Works perfectly fine for me with Elixir 1.8.1 & Erlang/OTP 21.

Comment: Sorry! I wanted to add my edit and comment to the answer of @Madasebrof below but I added it to yours by mistake! Really sorry, I reverted the answer back to as it was! Best regards, Serafeim

Comment: Why don't use `trunc` instead the option `[decimals: 0]`. One returns an integer, another a string... ```123.000 |> trunc```

Answer (score 10):

These answers are mostly odd. First, she didn't say anything about converting to a string. Second, there is certainly no need to jump into Erlang land!

In order:

```
Starting number: 123.101

Ending number: 123.101000 # Adding 3 digits to the precision of a float.

iex> 123.101 |> Decimal.from_float() |> Decimal.round(6)
#Decimal<123.101000>


Starting number: 123

Ending number: 123.000 # Adding 3 digits to the precision of an integer.

iex> 123 |> Decimal.from_float() |> Decimal.round(3)    
#Decimal<123.000>


Starting number: 123.101

Ending number: 123.1 # removing precision

iex> 123.101 |> Decimal.from_float() |> Decimal.round(1)
#Decimal<123.1>


Starting number: "123.000" # must be a string as 123.000 == 123.0

Ending number: 123 # removing precision

iex> "123.000" |> Decimal.new() |> Decimal.round(0)
#Decimal<123>
```

Once you have a number in `Decimal`, you can do what you want, e.g. convert to a float, convert to a string, etc.

```
iex> 123.101 |> Decimal.new() |> Decimal.round(6) |> Decimal.to_string()
"123.101000"

iex> 123.101 |> Decimal.new() |> Decimal.round(6) |> Decimal.to_float() 
123.101

iex> 123.101 |> Decimal.new() |> Decimal.round(0) |> Decimal.to_integer()
123
```

As an aside, I recommend working only in `Decimal` until you've finished any data manipulation, e.g. using `Decimal.mult(num1, num2)`, `Decimal.div(num1, num2)`, etc. `Decimal` rocks!

Comment: This is a great answer, but note that you need to add a third-party library.

Comment: Decimal.new() has been deprecated.  You should use Decimal.from_float() instead.

Comment: @Clinton check https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#new/1

Answer (score 7):

There isn't anything like this in Elixir's standard library as far as I know, but you can use `:io_lib.format/2` from Erlang to print a float with specific number of digits after the dot:

```
iex(1)> :io_lib.format("~.3f", [123.101])
['123.101']
iex(2)> :io_lib.format("~.6f", [123.101])
['123.101000']
iex(3)> :io_lib.format("~.3f", [123.0])
['123.000']
iex(4)> :io_lib.format("~.6f", [123.0])
['123.000000']
```

The returned value is an `iolist`, which can be converted to a binary using `IO.iodata_to_binary/1` if required (many functions that take a binary can accept an `iolist` directly as well, e.g. `IO.puts/1`):

```
iex(5)> :io_lib.format("~.6f", [123.0]) |> IO.iodata_to_binary
"123.000000"
```

`~.0f` doesn't work but for that you can simply call `trunc/1`:

```
iex(6)> trunc(123.123)
123
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [decimal](https://hexdocs.pm/decimal/Decimal.html#content) package for this previously

```
iex(6)> 123 |> Decimal.new() |> Decimal.round(3) |> Decimal.to_string()
"123.000"
```

In my case the data was already in Decimal format after being queried from the database.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, that’s how I would implement in in pure Elixir:

```
defmodule NumFmt do
  def format(value, pos, round? \\ true)
  def format(value, pos, _) when is_integer(value),
    do: format(Integer.to_string(value), pos)
  def format(value, pos, round?) when is_float(value),
    do: format(Float
               |> apply((if round?, do: :round, else: :floor), [value, pos]) 
               |> Float.to_string, pos)
  def format(value, 0, _) when is_binary(value),
    do: with [i | _] <- String.split(value, "."), do: i
  def format(value, pos, round?) when is_binary(value) do
    case String.split(value, ".") do
     [i] -> format(i <> ".0", pos, round?)
     [i, f] -> [i, f 
                   |> String.pad_trailing(pos, "0")
                   |> String.slice(0..pos - 1)] |> Enum.join(".")
    end
  end
end

IO.inspect NumFmt.format(123.101, 6), label: "123.101000"
#⇒123.101000: "123.101000"

IO.inspect NumFmt.format(123, 3), label: "123.000"
#⇒ 123.000: "123.000"

IO.inspect NumFmt.format(123.101, 1), label: "123.1"
#⇒ 123.1: "123.1"

IO.inspect NumFmt.format(123.000, 0), label: "123"
#⇒ 123: "123"
```

Comment: I really like your use of `with`. It makes that part of the code concise. The fact that it handles integers as the OP asked and rounding is nice too.